# I need to find all data which meets very complex criteria and cannot develop a formula/query top do so

Tags: sql-server, excel

I need to be able to find all 'requests' which meet the following criteria: more than 3 requests created on the same day, for the same memberID, for the same department. it must also show the 'scheme' (which is its own column). this can either be done in excel or SQL. thanks.
the columns available are 'requestID' 'memberID' 'Date Created''department''scheme.

[image: Below is an image of some sample data.]

Comment: Post what you have tried so far.

Comment: Also, [edit] your question to include the relevant tables with some sample data (DDL+DML is the best way to do it) and desired results. Think about it - If **you** can't figure out how to write it, how can **we** do it, **without even knowing the data structure?**

Answer (score 1):

You can query as below:

```
Select * from (
   Select *, RowCnt = Count(*) over(partition by  MemberId, Department, Convert(date, [Date Created]))
      from yourtable ) a
   Where a.RowCnt >= 3
```

Comment: Thank you, how would i edit this just to return the requests between the july 31st and August 6th?

Comment: you can add where condition inside subquery where datecolumn between 20170731 and 20170806

Comment: Would you be able to edit your initial answer to include the clause please? and also the column name for the date is briefdate. This is how the date appears in my data 04/08/2017  20:06:14.

Answer (score 0):

You an use WHERE EXISTS:

```
    SELECT r1.requestId,
       r1.memberID,
       r1.department,
       r1.[Date Created],
       r1.scheme
  FROM Requests r1
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM requests r2
               WHERE r2.memberId = r1. memberId
                 AND r2.department = r1.department
                 AND r2.[Date Created] = r1.[Date Created]
               GROUP BY r2.memberId,r2.departmetId,r2.[Date Created]
              HAVING COUNT(*) > 3)
   AND r1.[Date Created] > DATEADD(dd,-8,GETDATE())
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, as there is a large amount of records i would like to run this just for the the last week between the dates 31st July - 6th August

Comment: You just need to add additional criteria to the WHERE clause: